# How to choose random agent from a population and give every single person a random value?

Tags: anylogic

My current situation is that in a population, I have 3 types of agents divided into 3 sources. For example, the value of Agent A should between 3-5, B should between 5-7, and c should be between 8-9. And then, what I need is to get Everyone who enters the logic should have a different value between the numbers of these 3 groups and it has to be random. How to write a function or do something else that can get the result? I saw about choose a random agent from a population in the Anylogic Help, but I don't really understand.

Comment: when you say "the value" ... we don't know what it is

Answer (score 0):

You mention 3 different sources and 3 different agent types, so I assume you have a setup similar to the one below. There are 3 agent types, each created at a different source

In that case, you can easily in the o"on at Exit" code in the Actions section write code similar to what is in the screenshot `agent.variable = uniform_discr(3, 5);`

This assigns a value to a variable I created inside the agent between 3 and 5.

You just create similar code in each source for the different agent types and change the values in the random distribution sampling code `uniform_discr(min, max)`

[image]

If all the agents you create are in a population you can simply just cycle through the population for each type of agent and assign them a value like this

```
for(AgentA agent : agentApopulation) {
    agent.variable = uniform_discr(3, 5);
}
```